# onbeforeunload working but only on click in window

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onbeforeunload

My requirement is when a user refresh or closes the browser tab, his/her session would get invalidate. I searched for the events on closing and refreshing the browser and i got to know about onbeforeunload event.

But the problem is, **it is triggering only when I click on the window at least once.** I don't know exactly why this is happening may be DOM is not loading or any other reason. I want it to be triggered even when user didn't interacted with the web page.

I am using Mozilla Firefox 59.0.2 and Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181.

I am using onbeforeunload event handler as below. Here I just popping a alert box, if it will works I will add the code for invalidating the session:

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
return "All data that you have entered will be lost!";}
</script>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" background="banner_bg.gif" onbeforeunload="return OnBeforeUnLoad ()">
<img border="0" src="a.gif" align="left">
<img border="8" src="b.gif" align="right">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) you're not doing it right

Comment: Please place the contents of the script tag after the body tag ends.

Comment: @AlekhyaSatya, I tried it, didn't work I used the exact same code given in documentation that did not work either. May be this question is the duplicate of previous question but answer was not provided in that question. Please remove the duplicate tag from this.